# for loop and save Twitter data in different csv files

Tags: python, csv, for-loop, while-loop, tweepy

I am trying to extract tweets mentioning journalists' names or usernames. The search query is `cnn_search_query`  while the time of interest is between `start_time` and `end_time`. I wish to iterate through the three lists while at the same time saving the tweets in three different CSV files using the `date` in naming the CSV files.

I can successfully create the three CSV files `2022-02-02.csv`, `2022-01-31.csv`, and `2022-01-28.csv`. However, only the first CSV `2022-02-02.csv` actually contain data while `2022-02-02.csv` and `2022-01-31.csv` are left empty.

Can someone spot the mistake in my code? The issue is most likely in one of the loops.

```
cnn_search_query = ['(@Acosta OR "Jim acosta") -is:retweet', '(@Acosta OR "Jim acosta") -is:retweet', '(@jaketapper OR "Jake tapper") -is:retweet']
start_time = ['2022-01-27T21:58:59.000Z', '2022-01-25T21:58:59.000Z', '2022-01-22T21:58:59.000Z']
end_time = ['2022-02-06T21:58:59.000Z', '2022-02-04T21:58:59.000Z', '2022-02-01T21:58:59.000Z']
date = ['2022-02-02', '2022-01-31', '2022-01-28']
```

```
# Inputs for tweets
bearer_token = auth()
headers = create_headers(bearer_token)
max_results = 500

# Total number of tweets we collected from the loop
total_tweets = 0

# Inputs
count = 0  # Counting tweets per time period
max_count = 2000  # Max tweets per time period
flag = True
next_token = None


for i in date:

    # create csv files named after date
    csvFile = open(i + ".csv", "a", newline="", encoding='utf-8')
    csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)

    # create headers for the four variables: author_id, created_at, id, and tweet
    csvWriter.writerow(
        ['author_id', 'created_at', 'id', 'tweet'])
    csvFile.close()

    # Check if flag is true
    while flag:

        # Check if max_count reached
        if count >= max_count:
            break
        print("-------------------")
        print("Token: ", next_token)

        # loop over cnn_search_query, start_time, and end_time
        for query, start, end in zip(cnn_search_query, start_time, end_time):

            url = create_url(query, start, end, max_results)
            json_response = connect_to_endpoint(url[0], headers, url[1], next_token)
            result_count = json_response['meta']['result_count']

            if 'next_token' in json_response['meta']:
                #  Save the token to use for next call
                next_token = json_response['meta']['next_token']
                print("Next Token: ", next_token)
                if result_count is not None and result_count > 0 and next_token is not None:
                    print("Start Date: ", start_time)
                    append_to_csv(json_response, i + ".csv")
                    count += result_count
                    total_tweets += result_count
                    print("Total # of Tweets added: ", total_tweets)
                    print("-------------------")
                    sleep(5)
                    # If no next token exists
            else:
                if result_count is not None and result_count > 0:
                    print("-------------------")
                    print("Start Date: ", start_time)
                    append_to_csv(json_response, i + ".csv")
                    count += result_count
                    total_tweets += result_count
                    print("Total # of Tweets added: ", total_tweets)
                    print("-------------------")
                    sleep(5)

                # Since this is the final request, turn flag to false to move to the next time period.
                flag = False
                next_token = None
            sleep(5)
print("Total number of results: ", total_tweets)
```

The `append_to_csv`  function

```
def append_to_csv(json_response, fileName):
    # A counter variable
    counter = 0

    # Open OR create the target CSV file
    csvFile = open(fileName, "a", newline="", encoding='utf-8')
    csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)

    # Loop through each tweet
    for tweet in json_response['data']:
        # We will create a variable for each since some of the keys might not exist for some tweets
        # So we will account for that

        # 1. Author ID
        author_id = tweet['author_id']

        # 2. Time created
        created_at = dateutil.parser.parse(tweet['created_at'])

        # 3. Tweet ID
        tweet_id = tweet['id']

        # 4. Tweet text
        text = tweet['text']

        # Assemble all data in a list
        res = [author_id, created_at, tweet_id,
               text]

        # Append the result to the CSV file
        csvWriter.writerow(res)
        counter += 1

    # When done, close the CSV file
    csvFile.close()

    # Print the number of tweets for this iteration
    print("# of Tweets added from this response: ", counter)
```

Comment: Can you give more detail on your "append_to_csv()" function? As for now all you have mentioned about writing into csv is writing the header .

Comment: I have included the `append_to_csv()` function now :)

Answer (score 2):

Your `flag` is being set to `False` in the first iteration over `date` so it only ever passes `while flag` the first iteration:

```py
flag = True
next_token = None


for i in date:
    
    < cut >

    while flag:
        < cut > 
                flag = False
```

Comment: True! I removed the `flag = False` from the bottom of the code. Now all three CSV files contain data. However, the data is identical so there must be another issue in the for loop... Anyway, thank you